# Is it technically possible to remove some parts of the page UI without owning it?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am wondering if there is some page with too many advertisements, then is it possible to create my own simple UI and feed the input to that website ?
Lets say this site to send sms:
http://www.afreesms.com/intl/singapore

Now can I create an webpage with only Mobile number, SMS text input, display their verification code, and click send without having to see all other contents (Ads and stuffs).

Is it possible at all ?

Comment: Probably, you can access their webpage programatically and post the content to it. However, they may have defenses against that such as [captchas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA). And it may be a violation of their terms of use. If you want to send text messages from your own program, why not use [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)?

Comment: Technically possible, yes definitely. Feasible, maybe. Legally, my guess would be no, check their terms of service and their [usage policy](http://www.afreesms.com/aup).

Comment: so many issues with that idea. pratically speaking, even if you got it working, your site would be liable to break as soon as they changed something. check for api services instead. these wil be better supported and less liable to fail due to change.

Comment: Yeah, I know may not legally to use as a service but I just want to show case 1, 2 times. And I need a clean working sms sending UI.

Comment: ...a good example of site that people want to emulate the functionality of is twitter. these are their API docs... https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: @mason: I want to show their captchas on my page so it refresh with them.

Comment: @user1314404 Okay - so do that. We're not a code writing service, it's up to you. And we listed several good alternatives that would frankly be a lot easier.

Comment: How is it possible to send parameters from your website and click send (onclick event ) on their website ? I tried Twilio but its not free or open source API

Answer (score 0):

You can strip parts of the site out yes, it depends on the server setup wether you can post directly to it or not though.

If not there is a lot of sms api's available which only cost a few pence per send.

Comment: I just want to show case 1 or 2 times. Is there a quick and clean way with free of charge ?

Comment: @user1314404 Asking for us to recommend off-site resources is not allowed.